# Customize/Change Lead Conversion Wizard

Tags: apex, community, flow, lead-conversion

Is there any possibility  to make changes/customize the lead conversion process in SFDC?

Currently, when converting a lead, the conversion process limits the required fields.

In my case for instance, in order to manually create an account, the user has to input a field of the account.

However, when converting a lead to an account, they are able to bypass this requirement. This is one example of a field I'd like to add to the lead conversion page.

Comment: I have found that its our implementation as an idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bra8AAC  However , is there any workaround possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own lead conversion wizard using the [Lead Conversion Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm%23apex_dml_convertLead) and it's associated methods. If you search the boards you'll find a number of posts on custom classes and controllers that others have written to support their unique requirements.